# Upload Image/Video on S3 through Paperclip is too slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a Ruby on Rails application. In that I used Paperclip to upload image/video and store on AWS S3.

When I upload video (my video size is 10 MB) on S3, it will take more than 30 seconds. How can I speed up the process of uploading, so that it will take less than 5 seconds?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not with your local connection or is slowed down by something in your Rails app? Try running `rails c` on an AWS box and try the image upload from there.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not your network issue you can try two options for speeding up the process of upload to S3.

Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html

Or You can try [Bucket Explore](http://www.bucketexplorer.com)r which upload operations in hundreds of parallel queue, so that upload process is faster.